# Do α and β entail each other?

Tags: logic, proof

Show whether the following is true or false:

> α |= β or β |= α, for any two formulas α and β

I'm assuming here that α and β are formulas, not a set of formulas. My thought is that I can prove that it is false if I show α doesn't entail β and β doesn't entail α. I tried using a truth table to help me with this problem, but it didn't seem to help. I'm not sure how to go about this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Obviously not; consider **p** as α and **q** as β.

Comment: Already asked and answered in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2553033/for-any-formulas-%ce%b1-and-%ce%b2-do-they-entail-each-other).

Comment: Sorry, why does setting α and β as new variables make it clearer?

Comment: You have only to use [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Interpretation_of_a_sentence_of_truth-functional_propositional_logic) to check that neither **p ⊨ q** nor **q ⊨ p**, **as already answered to your question in MSE**.

Answer (score 3):

A set Γ entails the statement P if and only if there is no truth-value assignment in which every member of Γ is true and P false.

This is a standard def of entailment, check any textbook on formal logic. I would include a reference but that might be a product endorsement?

A simple truth table will show a row where α is true and β is false so ~( α|= β) and another row where β is true and α is false and thus ~( β |= α)

I've seen some debates regarding @FrankHubeny's answer but I believe the problem is that the OP's question was unclear due to a lack of precision.

1. I assume 'formula' means well-formed formula (wff) because I am not aware of any logic that operates on syntactically incorrect expressions.
2. Entailment is a relationship between a Set and a statement. Not between two statements/wff. Material implication operates between 2 statements. So talking about entailment between 2 formula is confusing and misleading.

I know that seems petty and pedantic, but Russell's Paradox shows us that it is *critical* to clearly define the scope of operators and that there can be profound problems if we apply functions incorrectly to sets, statements, classes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The question is how to understand why *(A → B) v (B → A)* is always true even when *A* and *B* are sentences that have nothing to do with each other. The reason is that the truth values for the conditional (→) and the disjunction (v) are defined to be true for three out of the four possible sets of valuations of A and B in such a way that their combination always yields a true result.

Consider the [truth table](https://mrieppel.net/prog/truthtable.html) for the conditional:

[image]

Note that there is only one way for the conditional to be false, but three ways for it to be true.

Similarly consider the disjunction:

[image]

Again, there is only one way for the disjunction to be false.

Furthermore, if we have *A → B* false then *B → A* would be true, but the only way for the disjunction to be false is if both of those conditionals are false. The OP noticed this:

> My thought is that I can prove that it is false if I show α doesn't entail β and β doesn't entail α.

Since it is not possible for both of those conditionals to be false, that makes the disjunction true for all valuations of *A* and *B*. The disjunction *(A → B) v (B → A)* is a tautology.

---

Note that the title question asks something different which may be where some of the difficulty comes from:

> Do α and β entail each other?

This question perhaps asks whether *(A → B) & (B → A)* or *A ↔ B* is always True?  However, *A* and *B* do not always entail each other as the following truth table shows.

[image]

Compare that result with the truth table for the disjunction:

[image]

The disjunction is a tautology because all of the valuations of the sentences *A* and *B* lead to a True result. The conjunction expressed in the title, however, is not a tautology.

---

Michael Rieppel. Truth Table Generator. Generated on May 9, 2019 from https://mrieppel.net/prog/truthtable.html

Comment: `The question is how to understand why (A → B) v (B → A) is always true` - That is not the question. There's a big difference between implication (→) and entailment (|=). And see Mauro's third comment above, which answers the question correctly.

Comment: @Eliran As the OP notes, "I'm assuming here that α and β are formulas, not a set of formulas." Note the last bullet point in the Wikipedia article that Mauro ALLEGRANZA cited in his third comment.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Interpretation_of_a_sentence_of_truth-functional_propositional_logic

Comment: I accept that A→B is logically valid (ie a tautology) iff A⊨B, as Wikipedia says, but that's different from what you did. You showed that (A→B)v(B→A) is a tautology, **not** that either A→B is a tautology or B→A is a tautology. Those are different things, and the latter does **not** hold.

Comment: @Eliran Neither A→B nor B→A are tautologies as can be seen from the first truth table in my answer. The OP is asking for the truth value of : *α |= β or β |= α, for any two formulas α and β*. To check this semantically with a truth table one is verifying that  ⊨(A→B)v(B→A) is a tautology, which it is.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the question. The question is whether, for any two formulas, one of the formulas entails the other. The answer is no. Neither of p and ~p entails the other.

Comment: @Eliran Put *(P>~P)v(~P>P)* in the truth table generator: https://mrieppel.net/prog/truthtable.html If P>~P is true, then ~P>P is false, and vice-versa. The OP has tried this: *My thought is that I can prove that it is false if I show α doesn't entail β and β doesn't entail α.*